# Troubleshooting a configure file, suspect line found but need to log vars

Tags: c, logging, configure

I have a problem & I need help. I'm trying to compile vim with python support but very slowly getting nowhere.

I've tried all sorts including work arounds/ fixes on here  & other forums.

I've now gone back to the beginning and am compiling, I get no errors when I do & don't run the --configure statement that enables python. However, when I examine the configure.log I see:

```
configure:5470: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_HOME=\"/usr/local\" -pthread  -I/usr/local/include  -Wl,-E   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c  -lselinux  -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic >&5
<command-line>:0:14: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
configure:5470: $? = 0
configure:5471: result: yes
```

and I have narrowed it down to the following line.

```
PYTHON_CFLAGS="-I${vi_cv_path_python_pfx}/include/python${vi_cv_var_python_version} -DPYTHON_HOME=\\\"${vi_cv_path_python_pfx}\\\""
```

Is there a way that I can check on the variables that are passed to this line? I'm not up on the C language. What can I put in the configure file so that it will output them to the log file?

Thanks in advance and I hope beyond hope that someone can help as over 12 hours of this are making me want to swear.

John

Comment: As configure.sh is a shell script, try adding an `echo ${PYTHON_CFLAGS}` after this variable is defined. You might even want to redirect the echo to a file `echo ${PYTHON_CFLAGS} > /tmp/file` for easier inspection.